# Compare input to a specific line saved in a text file JAVA

Tags: java, validation, loops, compare, text-files

In order to validate a country entered by the user, I'm trying to have that country input compared to a list of countries stored in a text file. If the input matches a country stored in the text file, the validCountry would be set to 'true' and the program would be able to proceed.This is what I've got so far:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String country = "";
    boolean validCountry = false;

    while (!validCountry)
    {
        System.out.print("Country: ");
        String countryIn = sc.next();
        try{
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("countries.txt"));
            while (scan.hasNext()) {
                String line = scan.nextLine().toString();
                if(line.contains(countryIn))
                {
                    country = line; 
                    validCountry = true;

                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
```

The above simply loops for me to re-input the country (implying that it is invalid).

This is what the countries.txt file looks like (obviously contains all the countries of the world not just the first few starting with 'A' :

```
Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa  
Andorra 
Angola  
Anguilla
...
```

I'm sure it's a very simple and minor error which I can't seem to find; but I've been trying to detect it for a while but to no avail. I've checked multiple other stackoverflow answers but they didn't seem to work either. I truly appreciate any form of help :)

Please let me know if my question needs further clarification.

Comment: what kind of error do you get? is the textfile correctly loaded?

Comment: I do not get any specific error, it simply loops back for me to input a country. 

I assume the text file is correctly loaded - otherwise the console would give me a 'file not found' error; which it doesn't..so I assume it is correctly loaded?

Comment: yes, if you don't  get an error there then it is probably correctly loaded. However maybe you check if scan.hasNext() ever returns true (by debugging or by a System.out.println()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the countries.txt file I had was encoded in UNICODE. All I had to do was change it to ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that in *String countryIn = sc.next();* the *sc* is a scanner that use *System.in*, change the *.next()* into **nextLine()**:

```
String countryIn = sc.nextLine();
```

then, you should also change *if(line.contains(countryIn))* because it will return true even if the given line is a substring of a country (*afg* will be found in *afghanistan* even though *afg* is not in the country list. use **equalsIgnoreCase** instead:

```
if (line.equalsIgnoreCase(countryIn)) {
...
}
```

Try if this class works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Country {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String country = "";
        boolean validCountry = false;

        while (!validCountry)
        {
            System.out.print("Country: ");
            String countryIn = sc.nextLine();
            try{
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("countries.txt"));
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    String line = scan.nextLine();
                    if(line.equalsIgnoreCase(countryIn))
                    {
                        country = line; 
                        validCountry = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, the sc is a Scanner that uses System.in. I've changed the .next() to .nextLine() and the .contains to .equalsIgnoreCase()...but it still doesn't work! The System.out.print("Country: "); re-loops for me to input a country - no matter whether I input complete rubbish or an actual country from the text file

Comment: Correct the countries.txt that you provided in the example: county names contains extra spaces at the end of the line. Try removing them from the file

Comment: I tried replacing the code in the if statement: from country = line; validCountry = true; to a simple System.out.print(line);...but it still reloops for me to input a country instead of prints out all the contents

Comment: well, if the condition in the if doesn't became true the code inside won't be executed. Did you try correcting the countries file?

Comment: Yep, I removed every extra at the end of every country... same problem :/

Comment: try the whole class i posted above. Notice that i added BREAK , because you don't need extra check after you've found a matching country. I also removed the .toString() because it isn't needed

Comment: I tried the whole class you sent (literally copy and pasted), but the same problem still occurs.. it reloops to the print statement for me to input a country. Thanks a million for taking the trouble to help.. do you have any other ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: add: System.out.println("\"" + countryIn + "\""); after String countryIn = sc.nextLine(); and add System.out.println("\"" + line + "\""); after String line = scan.nextLine(); and please post the complete output

Comment: I did so, ran it, entered "Malta" (which is a country on the list), and the result is this: 

Country: Malta
"Malta"
Country:

Comment: Nope, it doesn't.. :/ I tried a different method which involves uploading the items in the text file to an array list.. but even with that the items wouldn't print!

Comment: did you try to print the result of scan.hasNext()? are you sure that the file is correct? maybe it's linked to an existing but wrong file

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! The countries.txt file was encoded in UNICODE, all I had to do was change it to ANSI and now it works fine! I'm gobsmacked

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code and it works for me. 
I initialized your variable `sc` like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Note that it would be better to load the file outside the while loop (for better performance)

Comment: I've got no errors of compilation or out of bound errors or anything of that sort... the program simply seems to loop back for me to input a country! How has it worked for you?! What does it return?

Comment: I added a "System.out.println("ok: " + country);" at the end of your code and if I typed "Angola" it wrote me "ok: Angola".